# How can I give an ID to entities created in GraphQL using Sangria?

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

I have a case class of `Inventory`:

```scala
case class Inventory(
    organizationId: UUID,
    inventoryId: UUID,
    name: String,
    schema: String
)
```

An input type:

```scala
private val NewInventoryInputType =
    deriveInputObjectType[Inventory](
        InputObjectTypeName("NewInventory"),
        ExcludeInputFields("organizationId", "inventoryId")
    )
```

An argument:

```scala
val NewInventory = Argument("inventory", NewInventoryInputType)
```

And finally a field:

```scala
val MutationType = ObjectType("Mutation", fields[GraphQLContext, Unit](
    Field("createInventory", OptionType(UuidType),
        Some("Creates a new inventory."),
        NewInventory :: Nil,
        resolve = c => {
            val inventoryId = UUID.randomUUID
            val inventory = c arg NewInventory
            println(s"Inventory($inventory)")
            inventoryId
        }
    )
))
```

What I'd like to do is be able to create an `Inventory` with a query like this:

```
{
    "query": "mutation ($inventory: NewInventory!) { createInventory(inventory: $inventory) }",
    "variables": {
        "inventory": {
            "name":"i1",
            "schema":"s"
        }
    }
}
```

The missing piece is where to create the UUIDs for `organizationId` and `inventoryId` before Sangria attempts to instantiate an `Inventory` domain object using the variables it has.

Currently, I get this error:

```
Argument 'inventory' has invalid value: At path '/inventoryId': error.path.missing (line 1, column 67):
mutation ($inventory: NewInventory!) { createInventory(inventory: $inventory) }
                                                                  ^
```

(Of course, I could just create a `NewInventory` case class without the ID fields and instantiate an `Inventory` manually, but I'd like to avoid creating and maintaining two classes for each entity type.)

Comment: In my Sangria codebase I don't use any `deriveInputObjectType` because I don't like to have 1-to-1 coupling between my sangria types and my domain models.  I have cases where a single mutation might create 3,4, or 5 domain models, some of which are put in the DB etc.  Another reason  is exactly this case where you have an `ID` field in one and not the other.

Comment: @Tyler What do you do instead? Pass the fields as individual arguments?

Comment: Yes each of my mutations have individual parameters, and not just one parameter for the "object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are defining an input object for a case class, you need to define 2 things:

1. `InputObjectType` - it declares an input type in GraphQL schema and exposes it's meta-information via introspection API. In your example, you are defining it with a help of the `deriveInputObjectType[Inventory]` macro.
2. An implicit instance of [`FromInput[Inventory]` type class](http://sangria-graphql.org/learn/#frominput-type-class) - it provides an information on how to deserialize this input object from some input, like JSON. As you mentioned elsewhere, you are already defining it with some JSON library (`Json.format[Inventory]`)

Since you are excluding 2 fields from the definition of the input object, you also need to ensure that deserializer knows about it and it should be able to handle a scenario where these 2 fields are missing. In your case class, these 2 fields are non-optional which means that JSON library (I'm assuming you are using `play-json`) will always expect these 2 fields to be present. This is why you see this error: `Argument 'inventory' has invalid value: At path '/inventoryId'`. The error actually comes from `play-json` because in GraphQL Schema you allowed this field to be absent but JSON deserializer does not know about it

[`FromInput[Inventory]` type class](http://sangria-graphql.org/learn/#frominput-type-class) provides quite flexible mechanism though. I would suggest you to check it's documentation and maybe define your own implementation/wrapper that will handle these missing fields. An alternative approach would be to go more in direction of [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) and define 2 separate modes: one for queries and another one for mutation inputs (which also can be represented in scala code as 2 separate case classes). Of course, you also can define both optional fields as `Option[UUID]`.